# L'Hôpital's rule proof in Spivak Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

In chapter $11$ in *Spivak* *Calculus* he introduced *L'Hôpital's* *rule* that states that:
$1$$-$  $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=0$

$2-$ $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)=0 $

and if $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ *exists* then $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}     =\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

in the proof of *L'Hôpital's* *rule* he stated that $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ *exists* means two things

$(1)$ there is an interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ such that $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ exist for all $x$ in $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ except for $x=a$

$(2)$ in this interval $g'(x) \neq 0$                                                 [image]

My question is with the first assumption why $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ must be defined for all the interval $?$

the $\epsilon - \delta$               definiton  states that :

$∀ε>0$ $∃δ>0$ $:0<|x−a|<δ⟹∣f(x)−l∣<ε$

so if the function isn't defined at one point on the chosen interval this doesn't mean that it violates the  $\epsilon - \delta$ definiton

because there will be some points in the interval that  make $∣f(x)−l∣<ε$ when  $0<|x−a|<δ$

so it must for the limit to exsits that all the $x's$ in the domain of $f(x)$ fulfill the definiton not any $x$

so I don't see that it's a must for condition $(1)$ in the proof to be fulfilled

Correct me if there's anything wrong

Comment: Condition 1 is saying that $f'(x),g'(x)$ both exist for $0<|x-a|<\delta$, for some $\delta$ sufficiently small, not that they both exist for all $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$...

Comment: defined for all the *punctured* interval. The exceptional point could only be $x=a$. Choose any positive epsilon

Comment: $\delta$ isn't fixed. If, for some $x\in (a-\delta , a+\delta)$, either $f'(x)$ or $g'(x)$ doesn't exist, just choose a different $\delta$ smaller than $|x-a|$. Then the condition is satisfied. The idea is that $a$ isn't an isolated point or one-sided limit point.